# Plugin function scope issue

Tags: plugin-system, vim9script

I have recently discovered [this](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc) guide that was very eye opener under many aspects.

So I decided to do things "by the book" by moving my plugins in `~/.vim/pack/bundle/start/myplugin/plugin/myplugin.vim`.

However, I am having trouble in reckognizing the functions defined in a plugin that I am trying to write.

I try to explain better: say that `myplugin.vim` content is the following:

```
vim9script

if exists('g:myplugin')
    finish
endif

g:myplugin = 1

if !exists('g:myvar')
    g:myvar = 1
endif

def MyFunc()
    # do something
enddef

command! MyCommand call <sid>MyFunc()
```

If I `:echo g:myvar` I get `1`, but if I run `:MyCommand` I get `E117: Unknown function: <SNR>_45_MyFunc`

The problem can be solved by using `def g:MyFunc()` but firstly I am not sure if it is the right thing to do, and second I am bit puzzled because before re-shuffling things around, `:MyCommand` was working with `def MyFunc()`.
Before I had all my plugins in `.vim/bundle` folder.
The other plugins worked before and worked fine now - but mind that they are taken from the internet.
Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with windows vim 9.1.1392. What version are you trying?

Comment: MacVim 9.0.1276

Comment: Author of the linked guide, here. I haven't updated it for vim9script yet because I don't have enough experience with it (and I'm frankly not interested at this point). That said, your code doesn't throw any error, here, and I have the same version. Did you restart Vim in the meantime? Can we see your setup?

Comment: Congrats for the guide! :) Wait, now I am hooked in this autoload thing and I am rearranging my vimrc, etc, etc. I will link directly on github as soon as I will have done (and in the meantime I am also practicing to write a plugin :D ). Thanks for the help in the meantime!

Comment: @romainl Ok, I have finished to shuffle things around according to your guide. Things still does not work, but if I explicitly source the file in autoload/ then everything works...